# Remove subdomain from google and yahoo

Tags: seo, robots.txt

if I have a subdomain named abc.aaa.com

and now i have move to aaa.com/abc

more my server admin has help me to make a redirect on abc.aaa.com to aaa.com/abc

so no matter access which page/section/file in abc.aaa.com it will force to the HOME PAGE 
of aaa.com/abc

therefore i cant use robots.txt to disallow the subdomain

and even i cant submit to both yahoo and google webmaster

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting the subdomain is the correct course of action.  You **don't** want to use robots.txt.  If you did, googlebot couldn't crawl it anymore and see that it now resides in a new home.

Your redirect sounds problematic though. You should **not** be redirecting everything to the home page.  You should be redirecting each document to the new location of that document.  When you redirect to the home page, Google considers the redirect to be about the same as a 404.  They call it a "soft 404".  Redirecting to homepage will lose any search engine rankings those pages have and lose any credit you have for inbound links coming into that sub-domain.

Having implemented the redirect without robots.txt, both Google and Yahoo will pick up on the move. It should happen within a couple weeks.  There is no need for you to take further action.

Comment: Actually, my boss just not wish to see the old website in yahoo and google, although it has already effect, he think it is not good for his eyes